# PostgreSQL get record that will expire in next 2 days

Tags: postgresql

I'm using EXPIRY column as bigint storing epoch time. I need to find all those records which are going to expire in next 48 hours. 
Something like this:

```
select * from bottles where current_epoch_time - EXPIRY < 48 hours
```

I also need to order the records so that the bottle which will expire first should be the first record and the bottle that will expire last should be the last record.

I hope I was able to make my question clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select b.*
from bottles b
where EXPIRY >= extract(epoch from now()) and
      EXPIRY < extract(epoch from (now() + interval '48 hours') )
```

Notice that all the functions and calculations are not on `EXPIRY`.  This makes it easier for Postgres to use an index on that column -- speeding up the query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, perfect answer :)